# Update records imminently after rails controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, controller

My app has activity notifications, each has a flag 'seen' which I use to check if the user has looked at them.

My controller looks like this:

```
def index
  @unseen_activities = current_user.notifications.unseen.order(:updated_at => :desc)
  @seen_activities = current_user.notifications.seen.order(:updated_at => :desc)

  # mark them as viewed
  current_user.notifications.update_all(:seen => true)
end
```

But the activities are all loaded as having been seen, even though this is updated after the collections are made. What am I missing? #noob

Comment: Have you confirmed that `current_user.notifications.unseen.order(:updated_at => :desc)` does indeed include some unseen activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the marking as viewed in an `after_action` callback:

```
after_action :mark_as_seen

def index
  @unseen_activities = current_user.notifications.unseen.order(:updated_at => :desc)
  @seen_activities = current_user.notifications.seen.order(:updated_at => :desc)
end

private

def mark_as_seen
  current_user.notifications.update_all(:seen => true)
end
```

If that doesn't work, try to put an explicit render statement between fetching the notifications and updating there state.

If that doesn't work either, maybe mark them as seen in a background job, like Resque or Sidekiq.